# Select a folder in Blackberry webworks

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-webworks

Seems quite simple to select a file using webworks, what's not so simple is to select a folder, any one managed this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your answer is correct - you CANNOT select a folder using websworks, the method I used was to select a file in that folder, get that the location string of the file and remove the file name.

Obviously, if you don't have a file in that folder, it doesn't work.

Sucky, sucky.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to zip the folder into a single file and then run webworks on it.

As far as I know you can't run a webworks function on a folder.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the platform.  There is a blackberry.io.dir API that's supported on OS 5/6/7 and PlayBook: 
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.io.dir.html

BlackBerry 10 and PlayBook also support the HTML5 FileReader API which can be used to get at directory info:
https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/directoryentry.html

Answer (score 0):

There is another dirty workaround, you can use FilePicker with mode 
mode: blackberry.invoke.card.FILEPICKER_MODE_SAVER_MULTIPLE

This will allow you to select even an empty folder. The downside is that the user needs to click the Save button on the top of the card in order to get the folder path.

Sample code:

```
// filepicker options
var details = {
    mode: blackberry.invoke.card.FILEPICKER_MODE_SAVER_MULTIPLE,
};

blackberry.invoke.card.invokeFilePicker(details, function(path) {           
    alert('' + path);
},
```